# get most recent file (with same name) in subdirectories

Tags: linux, admin

Suppose you have 10 projects in subdirectories project_1, ..., project_10, all in parent directory projects.
All projects use the same lib, in project/project_n/lib/mylib
For particuliar reasons, mylib has to be copied in each project directory.
mylib files are modified from time to time when working in different projects. But usually modified on one project and not propagated on others.

I want to see the most recent file (for a given filename), scanning all projects. How would you do it?

Comment: to mannually solve the problem, an easy way is: tree -Df | grep <filename>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case, I guess there is a small trick you would like to know:

The **wildcards** (such as `*`) could also match the **directory name**.

So simply do:

```
ls -lt project/project_*/lib/mylib/filename
```

You could locate your file in the `project_1/` first with Tab skill very fast, then replace the `1` with `*`.

Comment: in fact my question was (over)simplified, in my real world situation, project directories have very different names.

Comment: @comte Same idea.  Just match like project/*/lib/mylib/filename, as soon as you have the same internal structure for all your directories and use the proper wildcard to match the different part.